# How to force decimal point after two digit in edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can I set the fractional point after two integers in android and set the limit to 55 digits only? After searching a lot I am posting my problem here. I have an `Edittext` with an  `android:inputType="number"` . I am able to set max limit to the `EditText` to 55 digits. I want user can able to type fractional digit also **between 0 to 55** digits like 24.22 or 52.88.

Can some please tell me how can I achieve this?
Here is my code.

```
public class FuelCostCalculator extends DialogFragment {

    EditText etLocation, etKilo, etLiter, etFuelCost;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.fullscreen_dialog);
    }

    private void init(View view) {
       //this is my editText
       etLiter = view.findViewById(R.id.etLiter);
       InputFilterMinMax filter = new InputFilterMinMax("0", "5499") {};
       etLiter.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});

    }
  }
```

My Filter class is :

```
public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

    private int min, max;

    public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
        this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
        this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        try {
            int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciated :

Comment: you can use text watcher on edit text.

Comment: TextWatcher dit not solve my issue

Comment: what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @SharartiKAKA have you read my question?

Comment: I think you want to apply periods (fullstop , dots) after every 2 digits. and they should be plot after every two digits user press?

Comment: Okay thanks to understanding and also want to set max limit to 55 @SharartiKAKA

Comment: have you tried masking ? well handling with text Watcher will be quiet complicated but it can surely do something with some logic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161079/discussion-between-champandorid-and-shararti-kaka).

Comment: I think no one is here to solve my issue?

Answer (score -1):

Check this answer . Though it is not so much clean but it will work as per your needs. Assuming that actAddItemFromDropdownList is your edit text and you have set maximum digits limit in your Xml.

```
int max =0;
String text ="";
actAddItemFromDropdownList.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            if(actAddItemFromDropdownList.getText().length()>0){
                if(text.equals(actAddItemFromDropdownList.getText().toString())){
                    text = "";
                }else {
                    text = actAddItemFromDropdownList.getText().toString();
                    max = max + 1;
                    if (max == 2) {
                        text = text + ".";
                        max = 0;
                        actAddItemFromDropdownList.setText(text);
                        actAddItemFromDropdownList.setSelection(actAddItemFromDropdownList.getText().length());
                    }
                }
            }



        }
    });
```

try it and if it works mark as selected answer.

Comment: Thanks let me check brother.

Comment: did not work brother if I entered 5 digits its automatically put a decimal point after the 4th one.

Comment: What i did with the understanding of your question, specifically what I said in comments. It will mark decimal automatically right after every 2 digits

Comment: It also marks decimal another decimal after 4 digits. BDW thanks for your time. Hope you understand.